# Redefinition of length?

Tags: javascript

When I try to create a variable named length

```
var length = 10;
```

JSLint complaints

> Redefinition of 'length'. var length = 10;

But where does that `length` come from?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AUNNU/)

Comment: Could you post the js you're using?  I'm assuming you're either overriding a global, or you have another length variable declared somewhere within your function (or it's parent function).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`window` already has `length` defined:

[window.length : Window Object](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0380__Window/windowlength.htm)

Comment: To further explain, if you are at the global scope (way up top, not in a function) and you create a variable with the same name as a property on window, then your variable *is* that property on window. A bizarre gotcha in JavaScript.

Comment: +1 Very obscure that length returns the number of frames within the window. JS can give some real headaches :-).

Comment: JS is like an American muscle car. A ripe pain in the ass, but oh so worth it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you had, say, an array:

```
howlong=myarray.length;
```

would return the number of elements in the array.

If you had a string:

```
howlong=mystring.length;
```

would return the number of characters in the string.

Long story short, 'length' is used all over the place. Most useful.

Comment: This is not what I had asked for.