# Why is the variable `closed` being logged as `false`, if I define it globally as `0`?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I know this must be really basic stuff but I don’t understand how the scope is working. I want the `closed` variable be known in the entire JavaScript file.

I have something like that (in jQuery):

```
var closed = 0;

$(function(){
  console.log(closed);
});
```

But `closed` is getting logged as `false`. I tried many things with `load` and `onload` functions, but I failed.

Comment: `closed` refers to `window.closed` in global scope. Don’t define variables globally. Wrap everything in an IIFE if you must.

Comment: it looks like an IIFE, your outside variable won't have access inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `let` instead of `var` as `closed` is a global variable used by JavaScript runtime so to make it local to the scope of the code you can use `let` instead of `var` which set the variable to global scope considering the global `closed` property.

```js
let closed=0;
$( function() {
    console.log(closed);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed Thanks.

Comment: @MinirockAkeru This answer didn’t explain _why_ you get `false` though. Not all variables behave like this.

Comment: This doesn’t even work in most cases. It works for `closed`, but wouldn’t work for `top`, even if they’re both non-writable, configurable, enumerable, non-setter getters on `window`.

Answer (score 5):

### The problem: global read-only properties

First, note that this problem exists in a Web environment, i.e. in a browser.
Other JS environments might not have this problem.

`var closed = 0;` in the global scope doesn’t create a binding that refers to a number and remains being the boolean `false`.

The reason for this is that `closed` refers to [`window.closed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/closed) in this circumstance; it’s always a boolean, and redefining it produces a linter warning like *“Redefinition of `closed`”*.

> This **read-only** property indicates whether the referenced window is closed or not.

Variable names that behave like this can be found in these lists:

- [`Window` properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window#Properties)
- [`WorkerGlobalScope` properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope#Properties)

There also used to be documentation on MDN about a mixin called `WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope`, whose properties would fit into this list; however, this just refers to things that are both in `Window` and in `WorkerGlobalScope`.
Tiny piece of context: MDN did a refactoring of their documentation where they removed all these “mixins” in favor of standard interface names.
You can find [archived versions of this list](https://web.archive.org/web/20210519161427/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope#Properties_2).

`Window` or `WorkerGlobalScope` are two of the interfaces that `globalThis` can be an instance of in Web environments.

Run the snippet to get a full list of variable names that you can’t safely use in the global scope:

```js
const props = Object.entries(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(globalThis)),
  undesirable = {
    set: (desc) => desc,
    configurable: (desc) => !desc,
    writable: (desc) => !desc
  };

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[id]"))
  .forEach((span) => span.innerHTML = props
    .filter(([prop, {[span.id]: desc}]) => undesirable[span.id](desc))
    .map(([prop]) => `<code>${prop}</code>`)
    .join(", "))
```

```css
code{
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1px 3px;
}
```

```html
<p>Properties that have a setter which may change the type or invoke some function, when a value is set to it:</p>
<span id="set"></span>

<hr/>

<p>Properties that are not configurable:</p>
<span id="configurable"></span>

<hr/>

<p>Properties that are read-only:</p>
<span id="writable"></span>
```

You’ll notice, it’s a *lot*.
It’s also a lot of short, common variable names like [`name`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10523701/4642212), `length` [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26591046/4642212), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8363302/4642212), `status` [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29685364/4642212), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40880958/4642212), `self`, [`top`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51235940/4642212), `menubar`, and [`parent`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74665612/4642212).
Furthermore, regarding the invocation of some function when assigning to a setter, something like `var location = "Podunk, USA";` actually [*redirects*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46029296/4642212) you to the location `./Podunk, USA`.

There’s a related issue of using function names like [`lang`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38276407/4642212), [`checked`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57499873/4642212), [`autocomplete`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32625930/4642212), [`evaluate`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69651785/4642212), or [`animate`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28173800/4642212) in event attributes like `onclick`: there, not only the `window` properties are included in the scope chain, but also all [scopable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/unscopables) properties of the entire prototype chain of the current `HTMLDocument` and of the current specific `Element` (e.g. using `<a onclick=""></a>` provides access to everything starting at `HTMLAnchorElement.prototype`) and perhaps some more, e.g. anything from the `form` property (of form elements) if it exists.

All this is also explained in this [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38276630/4642212).

This problem is also exhibited when relying on [DOM nodes with an `id` to become global properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3434278/4642212).

### Solutions

There is a handful of solutions to this.
I’ll list them in a subjective order of best to worst.

#### Use modules instead

Running your JavaScript code as [*modules*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) instead of scripts not only is the new cool thing to do, it also *just doesn’t have this problem*.

`index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Your site</site>
    <script type="module" src="main.mjs"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Content. -->
  </body>
</html>
```

`main.mjs`:

```js
const top = { spinning: true },
  window = { type: "clear", frame: "wood" };
let document = { type: "LaTeX", content: "\\documentclass[a4]{…} …" },
  closed = 0;
var location = "Podunk, USA";

// All of these are the variables defined above!
console.log({ top, window, document, closed, location });
```

Modules also come with a few other helpful features like implicit [deferment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) in relation to [DOM parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/4642212).

#### Wrap everything in a new scope

In a script’s global scope, you will encounter this problem.
In a new function scope, you don’t have this problem:

```js
(function(){
  const closed = 0; // Or `let` or `var`.
  
  $(function(){
    console.log(closed);
  });
})();
```

You can also create a more useful scope, for example jQuery’s `$(function(){`…`});` which waits for the DOM to be loaded.
*This*, by the way, is probably the option with the highest compatibility while still being one of the better options.

Since I don’t use jQuery, I prefer to wrap everything in a `DOMContentLoaded` listener where I can scope all the variables I need, and, in addition, use `"use strict";`:

```js
addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { "use strict";
  // Code goes here.
});
```

This avoids the clash between global properties and global variables.

#### Always use `const`. If you can’t use `const`, use `let`. If you can’t use `let`, use `var`.

… But you’ll never need `var`!<sup>1</sup>

Using `const` or `let` in scripts, as [Ankit Agarwal’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51062658/4642212) suggests, mitigates this problem:

```js
const closed = 0;

console.log(closed); // 0
```

However, this only works for *most* variable names, but not all — `const closed = 123; let history = "Hello, world!";` all work, but [`const window = 123;`, `const top = 123;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59285488/4642212) or `let document;` don’t.

<sup>1</sup>: Although there may be [one edge-case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38841469/4642212).
And obviously, older browsers still need `var`.

#### Just use different variable names

Sounds obvious, but this isn’t very robust.

New global properties may always pop up, so global variables may clash with them at any time.
Since this would obviously break several scripts all over the Internet, global properties which are added nowadays don’t really create much of an issue.
`const history = "Regency Era";` works just fine and makes `history` usable as a variable that refers to this string.
`var history =`…`;` still doesn’t, and it throws an error in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), and fails silently in loose mode.
**This has historically led to [compatibility issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24877236/4642212)** which is *why* this isn’t a robust option, especially when using `var`, which in turn is another strong argument against `var`.

Reassigning *older* properties, such as `document`, will fail in *scripts*, in certain environments, but **every variable name will work in a *module***, in every environment, which is why this is the top recommended option.

Comment: I currently don’t understand why (at least) `window`, `top` and `document` behave differently from all other properties when `const` or `let` is used in global scope. Maybe I or someone else can figure this out and refine the explanations given in this answer.