# Why variable 'name' is behaving weirdly?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript.

I have an index.html file with following content:

...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Section 2: JavaScript Language Basics</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Section 2: JavaScript Language Basics</h1>
    </body>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

...

Following are the contents of script.js:

```
var name = ['John', 'Mark', 'Jane'];

console.log(name[0]);
```

And the output I am getting in console window is 'J'.
When I change the name of the variable to names or something other valid name, the output is correct: 'John'

Could you please help me in understanding what is causing this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: Please also see [Why is the variable `closed` being logged as `false`, if I define it globally as `0`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51062916/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because there is already a variable exit as `window.name` that can only have string values and specifies window name. when you assign `name = ['John', 'Mark', 'Jane'];` the browser converts it to "John,Mark,Jane" Where `name[0]` is J;

## for experiment We just assign

`window.name` or `name = 4`

and when you check it's type

`console.log(typeof window.name)` or
`console.log(typeof name)`

it always return `string`

## detail guide at w3school

[w3school window.name](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_name.asp)