# Why status = null makes status = "null" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In a console, type:

```js
var status = null;
console.log(status);
console.log(status == null);
console.log(status === null);
console.log(status !== null);
```

[image]

Why `null` became a String `"null"`?

Comment: _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."_

Comment: Must be something special about `status`. If I use `foo` instead it works as expected

Comment: Please also see [Why is the variable `closed` being logged as `false`, if I define it globally as `0`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51062916/4642212).